# which-key takes up entire lower half of the screen (possibly related to package zoom)

Tags: window

Suddenly which-key, when triggered, takes up the entire lower half of the screen although only a portion of that is then filled with information. This behaviour started a couple of days ago, but I did not change the behaviour of which-key in any way.

```
(use-package which-key
  :ensure t
  :diminish which-key-mode
  :config
  (which-key-mode))
```

How can I change that?

Sometimes I think that the order in which my config file introduces packages is really crucial in terms of how emacs behaves, is that true?

Comment: "This behaviour started a couple of days ago, but I did not change the behaviour of which-key in any way." -- ok, but what *did* you change?  If you revert those changes, does the problem go away?

Comment: "Sometimes I think that the order in which my config file introduces packages is really crucial in terms of how emacs behaves" -- Your init file is a program written in the emacs lisp programming language, so sure, the order in which things occur can absolutely make a difference!

Comment: hard to say. I rewrote my entire configu basically. the minibuffer behaves normally for swiper, find file etc. though...

Comment: I suggest you use the recursive bisection technique to figure out what bit of your new config is causing this.

Comment: Does which-key use magit-popup?  This recently was replaced by transient inside magit.

Comment: how do I check if it does? and what does that mean? should I change something in my file? I do use magit, but it is not triggered of course if which key is invoked...

Answer (score 0):

By default which-key uses what it calls side-window that confusingly is below the current window. The variable below controls the portion of the frame the which-key window can take. Check and adjust the value:

```
;; max height of which-key window, when displayed at top or bottom.
;; valid values: number of lines (integer), or percentage out of current
;; frame's height (float larger than 0 and smaller than 1)
(setq which-key-side-window-max-height 0.25)
```

More at https://github.com/justbur/emacs-which-key

Comment: the initial problem was related to the zoom package, which I use to dynamicallyt adjust buffer sizes when switching between them. Zoom allows to define modes that are disregarded though. Is switch keys minor mode called : which-key-mode? if so it does not work...

Comment: The use of the zoom package (zoom-window?) is crucial information missing in your question. Please update the question. Does which-key work as expected after disabling zoom? The mode is which-key-mode.

Comment: it does, I update the question accordingly